# Can't write into offline database

Tags: c#, android, database, unity-game-engine

I have this script in Unity 4..

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Data;
using Mono.Data.SqliteClient;
using System.IO;


public class dbAccess : MonoBehaviour {
    private string connection;
    private IDbConnection dbcon;
    private IDbCommand dbcmd;
    private IDataReader reader;

public string nama;

    void OnGUI()
        {
            GUI.Box(new Rect(150,50,200,200),"Nama");
            nama = GUI.TextField(new Rect(50,30,100,20),nama,25);
            string[] values = {"NULL", nama};

            if(GUI.Button(new Rect(65,50,70,20),"Ok"))
            {
                InsertInto("user", values);
            }
        }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        if(!PlayerPrefs.GetInt("first_run").Equals(1))
        {
            String _databaseFileName = "mydatabase.sqlite";
            String _databasePath = Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + _databaseFileName;
            StartCoroutine(ExtractFileFromJar(_databaseFileName, _databasePath));
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("first_run",1);
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerator ExtractFileFromJar(string dbName,string writePath)
    {
        WWW loadDb = new WWW("jar:file://" + Application.dataPath + "!/asset/!" + dbName);
        yield return loadDb;
        File.WriteAllBytes(writePath, loadDb.bytes);
    }


    public void OpenDB(string p)
    {
        connection = "URI=file:mydatabase.sqlite" + p;
        dbcon = new SqliteConnection(connection);
        dbcon.Open();
    }

    public void CloseDB()
    {
        reader.Close();
        reader = null;
        dbcmd.Dispose();
        dbcmd = null;
        dbcon.Close();
        dbcon = null;
    }

    IDataReader BasicQuery(string query)
    {
        dbcmd = dbcon.CreateCommand();
        dbcmd.CommandText = query;
        reader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader();
        return reader;
    }

    int CreateTable(string name, string[] col, string[] colType)
    {
        string query;
        query = "CREATE TABLE" + name + "(" + col[0] + " " + colType[0];
        for(var i=1; i<col.Length; i++){
            query += "," + col[i] + " " + colType[i]; 
        }
        query += ")";
        try{
            dbcmd = dbcon.CreateCommand();
            dbcmd.CommandText = query;
            reader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Debug.Log(e);
            return 0;
        }
        return 1;
    }

    int InsertIntoSingle(string tableName, string colName, string value)
    {
        string query;
        query = "INSERT INTO" + tableName + "(" + colName + ")" + "VALUES (" + value + ")";
        try{
            dbcmd = dbcon.CreateCommand();
            dbcmd.CommandText = query;
            reader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Debug.Log(e);
            return 0;
        }
        return 1;
    }

    int InsertIntoSpecific(string tableName, string[] col,string[] values)
    {
        string query;
        query = "INSERT INTO" + tableName + "(" + col[0];
        for(int i=1; i<col.Length; i++){
            query += "," + col[i];
        }
        query += ") VALUES (" + values[0];
        for(int i=1; i<values.Length; i++){
            query += "," + values[i];
        }
        query += ")";
        try{
            dbcmd = dbcon.CreateCommand();
            dbcmd.CommandText = query;
            reader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Debug.Log(e);
            return 0;
        }
        return 1;
    }

    int InsertInto(string tableName, string[] values)
    {
        string query;
        query = "INSERT INTO" + tableName + "VALUES(" + values[0];
        for(int i=1; i<values.Length; i++){
            query += ")" + values[i];
        }
        query += ")";
        try{
            dbcmd = dbcon.CreateCommand();
            dbcmd.CommandText = query;
            reader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Debug.Log(e);
            return 0;
        }
        return 1;
    }

    public string[] SingleSelectWhere(string tableName, string itemToSelect, string wCol, string wPar, string wValue)
    {
        string query;
        query = "SELECT" + itemToSelect + "FROM" + tableName + "WHERE" + wCol + wPar + wValue;
        dbcmd = dbcon.CreateCommand();
        dbcmd.CommandText = query;
        reader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader();
        string[] readArray = new string[reader.RecordsAffected];
        int i=0;
        while(reader.Read()){
            readArray[i] = reader.GetString(0);
            i++;
        }
        return readArray;
    }

    void Update () {

    }
}
```

when I insert name and then click "**OK**" button,

it can't insert into my database..

can someone help me fix my script?

I'm newbie at C# and I'm very confused..

Thanks for your help..

Answer (score 0):

Your missing some spaces with your string concatenating.

```
query = "INSERT INTO " + tableName + " (" + colName + ") " + "VALUES (" + value + ")";
```

This can also leave you open to sql injection. Use `Parameterized Queries`.

Comment: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at dbAccess.InsertInto (System.String tableName, System.String[] values) [0x00043] in C:\Users\budi\Documents\testDB\Assets\dbAccess.cs:154 
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
dbAccess:InsertInto(String, String[]) (at Assets/dbAccess.cs:159)
dbAccess:OnGUI() (at Assets/dbAccess.cs:25)

Comment: Did you add some spaces around the objects in the query like I showed? Do you see the diff in my line vs. yours?

Comment: Show your changes - there may still be something missing.

Answer (score 0):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Data;
using Mono.Data.SqliteClient;
using System.IO;


public class dbAccess : MonoBehaviour {
    private string connection;
    private IDbConnection dbcon;
    private IDbCommand dbcmd;
    private IDataReader reader;

public string nama;

    void OnGUI()
        {
            GUI.Box(new Rect(150,50,200,200),"Nama");
            nama = GUI.TextField(new Rect(50,30,100,20),nama,25);
            string[] values = {"NULL", nama};

            if(GUI.Button(new Rect(65,50,70,20),"Ok"))
            {
                InsertInto("user", values);
            }
        }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        if(!PlayerPrefs.GetInt("first_run").Equals(1))
        {
            String _databaseFileName = "mydatabase.sqlite";
            String _databasePath = Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + _databaseFileName;
            StartCoroutine(ExtractFileFromJar(_databaseFileName, _databasePath));
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("first_run",1);
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerator ExtractFileFromJar(string dbName,string writePath)
    {
        WWW loadDb = new WWW("jar:file://" + Application.dataPath + "!/asset/!" + dbName);
        yield return loadDb;
        File.WriteAllBytes(writePath, loadDb.bytes);
    }


    public void OpenDB(string p)
    {
        connection = "URI=file:mydatabase.sqlite" + p;
        dbcon = new SqliteConnection(connection);
        dbcon.Open();
    }

    public void CloseDB()
    {
        reader.Close();
        reader = null;
        dbcmd.Dispose();
        dbcmd = null;
        dbcon.Close();
        dbcon = null;
    }

    IDataReader BasicQuery(string query)
    {
        dbcmd = dbcon.CreateCommand();
        dbcmd.CommandText = query;
        reader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader();
        return reader;
    }

    int CreateTable(string name, string[] col, string[] colType)
    {
        string query;
        query = "CREATE TABLE" + name + "(" + col[0] + " " + colType[0];
        for(var i=1; i<col.Length; i++){
            query += "," + col[i] + " " + colType[i]; 
        }
        query += ")";
        try{
            dbcmd = dbcon.CreateCommand();
            dbcmd.CommandText = query;
            reader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Debug.Log(e);
            return 0;
        }
        return 1;
    }

    int InsertIntoSingle(string tableName, string colName, string value)
    {
        string query;
        query = "INSERT INTO" + tableName + "(" + colName + ")" + "VALUES (" + value + ")";
        try{
            dbcmd = dbcon.CreateCommand();
            dbcmd.CommandText = query;
            reader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Debug.Log(e);
            return 0;
        }
        return 1;
    }

    int InsertIntoSpecific(string tableName, string[] col,string[] values)
    {
        string query;
        query = "INSERT INTO" + tableName + "(" + col[0];
        for(int i=1; i<col.Length; i++){
            query += "," + col[i];
        }
        query += ") VALUES (" + values[0];
        for(int i=1; i<values.Length; i++){
            query += "," + values[i];
        }
        query += ")";
        try{
            dbcmd = dbcon.CreateCommand();
            dbcmd.CommandText = query;
            reader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Debug.Log(e);
            return 0;
        }
        return 1;
    }

    int InsertInto(string tableName, string[] values, string colName)
    {
        string query;
        query = "INSERT INTO " + tableName + " (" + colName + ") " + "VALUES (" + values[0] + ")";
        for(int i=1; i<values.Length; i++){
            query += ")" + values[i];
        }
        query += ")";
        try{
            dbcmd = dbcon.CreateCommand();
            dbcmd.CommandText = query;
            reader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Debug.Log(e);
            return 0;
        }
        return 1;
    }

    public string[] SingleSelectWhere(string tableName, string itemToSelect, string wCol, string wPar, string wValue)
    {
        string query;
        query = "SELECT" + itemToSelect + "FROM" + tableName + "WHERE" + wCol + wPar + wValue;
        dbcmd = dbcon.CreateCommand();
        dbcmd.CommandText = query;
        reader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader();
        string[] readArray = new string[reader.RecordsAffected];
        int i=0;
        while(reader.Read()){
            readArray[i] = reader.GetString(0);
            i++;
        }
        return readArray;
    }

    void Update () {

    }
}
```

like that?